# Flutter Custom Splash View

Tags: android, flutter, splash-screen

Trying to implement a custom splash screen view in Flutter android. Launchbackground.xml not working for my requirement. I have 2 images one background and other position top image.

Trying this url custom splash screen session
[Creating a custom SplashScreen](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen)

Share sample code

```
class SplashScreen : SplashScreen {
override fun createSplashView(context: Context, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
    //return SplashActivity();
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_splash, null, false);

}

override fun transitionToFlutter(onTransitionComplete: Runnable) {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
    //mySplashView.animateAway(onTransitionComplete);
    onTransitionComplete.run();
}
```

}

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/spalshscreenbg"
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo_id"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:src="@drawable/topimage"/>
```

Comment: Black screen displaying first and then only displaying splash view.

is this because of theme settings in manifest.xml file

android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"

Answer (score 0):

You could try this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash as it does a lot of the work for you. This is only a suggestion and should definitely be a comment but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: While using single image solution like background theme option, image stretches. Splat image into 3 parts thats why plugin may not works.